# Dogecoin Core Wallet 1.10 - Help - Encrypt Wallet Option not available to allow staking

Tags: dogecoin

Help,

I am new to staking using crypto currency wallets.

I have download the Dogecoin Core Wallet 1.10 and the Encrypt Wallet Option is greyed out. How can I encrypt this wallet for staking please? I have other wallets for other crypto currencies that are all staking fine.

Thanks in advance.

Declan

Comment: Hey Declan, do you mean "staking" as in "mining in a proof-of-stake cryptocurrency"? Dogecoin uses a proof-of-work algorithm, so if that's what you mean, there is no staking in Dogecoin. See: [What is proof-of-stake?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9082/5406)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I meant proof-of-stake. Best Wishes, Declan

Answer (score 1):

Staking is only used with [proof-of-stake](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9082/5406) cryptocurrencies. Dogecoin uses a proof-of-work algorithm, so there is no staking in Dogecoin.