# proof of stake concept and implementation confusion

Tags: currencies, cryptography, proof-of-stake

i'm currently studying proof of stake concept in cryptocurrency in preparation of building it soon, but i still have some doubts about my understanding of the concept itself, and i have a lot of questions about it.

IF i set the max supply of 21 millions coins, question is :

1. do i have to premine all the coins (21 millions of them) and put it in the programs's wallet? or just let it not mined at first, and release the coins when the forger have solved a block?
2. do i have to build an offline wallet (windows, mac, linux os) or is an online web wallet will be enough for POS staking?
3. about the POS itself, lets say for example there are 100 stakers, with various amount/percentage of coins staked, i understand they're given interest lets say for example 5% a year on their staked coins, which stakers will given a block to solve the hashing problem? will it be random based on their percentage of stakes? will the comission of solving the block go to the solver (1 staker) or go to all of the stakers by percentage of their stake percentage (100 stakers).
4. according to [What is proof-of-stake?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9082/what-is-proof-of-stake) it was said that someone possessing 1% of the total stakes "mine" 1% of the total blocks, it gets confusing here, if example 1 block contains 100 transaction, so this 1% stakers will be solving hash of 1 transaction? is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first three questions are questions about what you want to do. We have no way to know what you want to do. Your fourth question is technical:

> according to What is proof-of-stake? it was said that someone possessing 1% of the total stakes "mine" 1% of the total blocks, it gets confusing here, if example 1 block contains 100 transaction, so this 1% stakers will be solving hash of 1 transaction? is this correct?

No. A staker who holds 1% of the stake will mine 1% of the blocks. That means one out of 100 blocks will, on average, be mined by them. That block can contain 100 transactions or no transactions, that staker would typically have free choice of what to put in the blocks they produce.

Comment: i believe my first 3 questions IS NOT WHAT I WANT TO DO, i believe i'm asking people WHAT I SHOULD DO. let me rephrase the question to make this clear : 1. "DO I HAVE TO" premine all the coins (21 millions of them) and put it in the programs's wallet OR DO I HAVE TO or just let it not mined at first, and release the coins when the forger have solved a block? WHICH SHOULD I DO? i believe that's not asking WHAT I WANT TO DO. same goes with point 2 and 3 on my questions list.

Comment: for point number 4, about your answer, lets say if a blockchains contain 10 blocks, with 10 transactions inside, the staker have only 1% of stake, how many blocks will he mine? and also you're saying staker could CHOOSE what to put in the blocks? what do you mean by this?

Comment: @HandyWijaya If he has 1% of the stake, on average he will mine 1% of the blocks. Just like a person who buys 1% of all lottery tickets sold will on average win 1% of the prizes. Yes, in most schemes, each miner/staker gets to choose what to put in the blocks they mine.

Comment: i still don't get detailed enough. example in MYCOIN i have a blockchain with 10 blocks in it, inside each blocks it has 10 transactions in it. so the 1% stakers with get to mine 1% x 10 blocks = 0,1 block? or no block at all due to 0,1 block not 1 full block? but if he gets to mine 1 block, lets say he choose the last block (the 10th block), it means he has to wait for the other previous 9 blocks to be mined first then he gets to mine that 1 last block? sorry for the more detailed question, but i have a very deep confusion on this topic.

Comment: @HandyWijaya For any given block, a person who has 1% of the staking of the people who are trying to make a block at that time has a 1% chance of making that particular block. It's just like a lottery. For each drawing, a person who has 1% of the tickets has a 1% chance of winning. If he's waiting for something, he has 0 chance. Only those trying to mine a block can mine a block. If he's trying, his chance of succeeding is in proportion to how much of the stake of those trying is his. In most schemes, each block is independent.

Comment: okay, i understand now, after many confusing reading on google plus your helpful answer, i can summarize that in POS, it's just a matter of luck like a lottery, people who only investing of total 1% of stake may not be mining a block due to only 1% of chance ya? i think this POS scheme isn't fair for the whole investor, i'm gonna implement my own POS system now which guarantee all investors big and small have their earnings even with just 1% of stake. THANK YOU VERY MUCH David.

Comment: @HandyWijaya You will have a *very* hard time designing such a system as there are numerous unsolved problems you will have to solve. If we all know, per the rules, that a particular person must generate the next block, what happens if they don't? Will the system just halt? How will a consensus form on when to give up waiting? (Make sure you develop a very detailed understanding of the problem you're trying to solve before you start proposing novel solutions to it! The primary problem is how to deal with numerous hostile participants and relying on one of them is bad.)